# Render problem - only rendering for 2 seconds

Tags: rendering, animation, render-layers

I am trying to render an animation looped that i made, but i am kinda beginner at rendering animation and i have an issue. When i render, i only got 2 seconds of the animation... I am trying to render at 30fps, and the animation is long 805 frames. What settings i need to change? [image]

Comment: Do you render the animation as an image sequence or video file? Have you checked the output folder?